# How to set src when 2 values are choosen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got problem. I want to change image src when you choose 2 values in 2 lists. I mean is it possible when you choose "audi", choose all of the models but when you choose "bmw", won't be able to get bmw/a3. After choosing "bmw" you have to select model before getting value.

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li')
const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.list li')

let src = {
    company: `audi`,
    model: `a3`
}
const chooseCompany = (e) => {
    list.forEach(li => {
        li.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const origin = e.target;
            const audi = document.querySelector('.audi')
            const bmw = document.querySelector('.bmw')
            const fiat = document.querySelector('.fiat')
            if (origin.dataset.companyName === "audi") {
                audi.classList.remove('is-hidden')
                bmw.classList.add('is-hidden')
                fiat.classList.add('is-hidden')
            }
            else if (origin.dataset.companyName === "bmw") {
                audi.classList.add('is-hidden')
                bmw.classList.remove('is-hidden')
                fiat.classList.add('is-hidden')

            }
            else if (origin.dataset.companyName === "fiat") {
                audi.classList.add('is-hidden')
                bmw.classList.add('is-hidden')
                fiat.classList.remove('is-hidden')
            }
        })
    });
}

const pickCompany = (e) => {
    const origin = e.target;
    src.company = origin.dataset.companyName;
    console.log(src)
}
const pickModel = (e) => {
    const origin = e.target;
    src.model = origin.dataset.modelName;
    console.log(src)
}
list.forEach(li => {
    li.addEventListener('click', chooseCompany)
    li.addEventListener('click', pickCompany)
})
menu.forEach(li => {
    li.addEventListener('click', pickModel)
})
console.log(`src='assets/${src.company}/${src.model}'`)
```

```css
ul li{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu{
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  .menu li{
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  .is-hidden{
    display:none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li data-company-name="audi">audi</li>
            <li data-company-name="bmw">bmw</li>
            <li data-company-name="fiat">fiat</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul class="list audi">
        <li data-model-name="a3">a3</li>
        <li data-model-name="a4">a4</li>
        <li data-model-name="a5">a5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class=" list bmw is-hidden">
        <li data-model-name="e39">e39</li>
        <li data-model-name="e46">e46</li>
        <li data-model-name="e90">e90</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list fiat is-hidden">
        <li data-model-name="punto">punto</li>
        <li data-model-name="panda">panda</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If something is unclear feel free to ask :)

Comment: Why exactly do you need to set the variable only after you select a model? Are you going to use that to change the `src` of an image? If you're only going to change an image src can't you just do it in the `pickModel` function? That way it will always set the path correctly

Comment: @Gunther this is exactlly what I wanted :) This was so simple! I'm really appreciate.

Comment: The funny thing is that I was actually thinking that I didn't understand your problem, that's the reason I didn't post it as an answer, lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to your `pickCompany` function. This would check if the incoming company is different from the current one. If it is, clear the current model. Here's what I mocked up.

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li')
const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.list li')

let src = {
    company: `audi`,
    model: `a3`
}
const chooseCompany = (e) => {
    list.forEach(li => {
        li.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const origin = e.target;
            const audi = document.querySelector('.audi')
            const bmw = document.querySelector('.bmw')
            const fiat = document.querySelector('.fiat')
            if (origin.dataset.companyName === "audi") {
                audi.classList.remove('is-hidden')
                bmw.classList.add('is-hidden')
                fiat.classList.add('is-hidden')
            }
            else if (origin.dataset.companyName === "bmw") {
                audi.classList.add('is-hidden')
                bmw.classList.remove('is-hidden')
                fiat.classList.add('is-hidden')

            }
            else if (origin.dataset.companyName === "fiat") {
                audi.classList.add('is-hidden')
                bmw.classList.add('is-hidden')
                fiat.classList.remove('is-hidden')
            }
        })
    });
}

const pickCompany = (e) => {
    const origin = e.target;
    if (src.company !== origin.dataset.companyName) {
        src.company = origin.dataset.companyName;
        src.model = null;
    }
    console.log(src);
}
const pickModel = (e) => {
    const origin = e.target;
    src.model = origin.dataset.modelName;
    console.log(src)
}
list.forEach(li => {
    li.addEventListener('click', chooseCompany)
    li.addEventListener('click', pickCompany)
})
menu.forEach(li => {
    li.addEventListener('click', pickModel)
})
console.log(`src='assets/${src.company}/${src.model}'`)
```

```css
ul li{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu{
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  .menu li{
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  .is-hidden{
    display:none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li data-company-name="audi">audi</li>
            <li data-company-name="bmw">bmw</li>
            <li data-company-name="fiat">fiat</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul class="list audi">
        <li data-model-name="a3">a3</li>
        <li data-model-name="a4">a4</li>
        <li data-model-name="a5">a5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class=" list bmw is-hidden">
        <li data-model-name="e39">e39</li>
        <li data-model-name="e46">e46</li>
        <li data-model-name="e90">e90</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list fiat is-hidden">
        <li data-model-name="punto">punto</li>
        <li data-model-name="panda">panda</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's fine, but there is one issue. If you set src.model as null, img src won't be found. I think solution for this is to change src only in pickModel function :)

Comment: Ahhhh, I got the order of operations mixed up, but you're absolutely correct :)